# Gajim - obtaining the latest version

Tags: 20.04, updates, repository, client, xmpp

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and installing gajim over `apt install` but I only get 1.1.3-2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I update to the latest version, 1.3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ubuntu is based on Debian, you could use the latest Debian package, [Package: gajim (1.3.0-1)](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gajim). You have two options for installation method:

- Command line
- GUI

First download the `.deb` file.

#### Command Line

You can use either `dpkg` or `apt`:

```
sudo dpkg -i <path to .deb file>
```

or

```
sudo apt install <path to .deb file>
```

So,

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/gajim_1.3.0-1_all.deb
```

#### GUI installation

Double click the `.deb` package and the **Software Center** should open and offer to install the package for you.

If, for some reason, the **Software Center** doesn't open automatically when you double click, then right click the package, and select **Open With** and *then* choose the **Software Center**.

Alternatively, instead of the **Software Center**, you could use **gdebi**. If you don't already have **gdebi**, install it with the Software Center (oh, the irony).

Comment: Thank you, i was able to install v1.3.0 but full of bugs, did you know any good related alternative? :)